# Обозначение итерации начиная с 2 Twig

Tags: php, twig

Есть цикл в Twig

```
{% for user in users %}
{{ loop.index }} - {{ user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

При каждой итерации выводиться

> 1 - user1   2 - user2 итд.

Как сделать чтоб loop.index начинался  с 2

> 2 - user1   3 - user2 итд.

Comment: Вместо `{{ loop.index }}` напишите `{{ loop.index + 1 }}`

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for user in users|slice(1) %}
{{ loop.index }} - {{ user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if loop.first == false %}
    {{ user.username | raw }}
{% endif %}
```